# How to run an applymap function using grouby in pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

In a pandas Dataframe I want to `applymap(somefunction)` using `groupby` (using some column index values), which I am finding really difficult to accomplish.

**mcve_01.txt**

```
pos         f1_index      M1       M2      F1_x 
16230484    141      G/G      G/G       G
16230491    141      C/C      C/C       C
16230503    141      T/T      T/T       T
16232072    211      A/A      A/A       A
16229783    211      C/C      C/C       G
16229992    211      A/A      A/A       G
16230007    211      T/T      T/T       A
16230011    263      G/G      G/G       C
16230049    263      A/A      A/A       T
```

I read the above file and set the `pos` and `f1_index` to index and rest of the column values to list:

```
mcve_data.set_index(['pos', 'index'], append= True, inplace = True)
mcve_list = mcve_data.applymap(lambda c:[list(c)])
```

So, now I want to read two lines (values) at the time and create either **`itertools.product` vs `zip`** of the two values using the function described below. ***I am not sure if this function is going to be useful but hope it helps the reader.***

```
def mapfun(c):
if any(['.' in l for l in c]):
    return '.'

if all(['|' in l for l in c]):
    fun = zip

else:
    fun = product

filt_set = set(['|','/'])
filt = partial(filter,lambda l: not (l in filt_set))

return ','.join('g'.join(t) for t in fun(*map(filt, c)))
```

**Final code: I take the above function and read two lines at a time using `mcve_list+mcve_list.shift(1):**

```
mcve_mm = (mcve_list+mcve_list.shift(1)).dropna(how='all').\
    applymap(mapfun)
```

which gives me **(final output) like**:

```
pos    index      M1        M2      F1_x    
16230484    141  CgG,CgG,CgG,CgG        CgG,CgG,CgG,CgG         CgG
16230491    141  TgC,TgC,TgC,TgC        TgC,TgC,TgC,TgC         TgC
.....      ...   TgT,TgT,TgT,TgT        TgT,TgT,TgT,TgT         TgT
```

**Thing I want to fix - this is the problem:**

All is fine with the above (function code) and final code except that now I want to run the function separately for each `f1_index` values. Doing this by group will not product or zip the list when the index value changes.

**Things I tried:**

- reseting the `f1_index` and then groupby('f1_index')

  ```
  mcve_group = mcve_list.reset_index(level=['f1_index'])
  mcve_group2 = mcve_group.groupby('f1_index')

  for x, group in mcve_group2:
      mcve_mm2 = (mcve_group2+mcve_group2.shift(1)).dropna(how='all').\
      apply(mapfun)
  ```

  And, also:

  ```
  mcve_mm2 = (mcve_group2+mcve_group2.shift(1)).dropna(how='all').\
      apply(lambda x: [mapfun(c) for c in x])
  ```
- using groupby('key')

  ```
  mcve_mm = (mcve_list+mcve_list.shift(1)).groupby('f1_index').dropna(how='all').\
  applymap(mapfun)
  ```
- Wrapping the applymap

  ```
  mcve_mm = (mcve_list+mcve_list.shift(1)).dropna(how='all').groupby(['f1_index'], group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: [mapfun])
  ```

I didn't get any error but the function part got messed up when trying to groupby and then apply.

I am also not finding any examples and tutorial that uses applymap along with groupby in pandas df.

Comment: I don't understand how you got your "final output".  Can you verbally explain the reasoning that leads from your input to that output?  Also, I don't understand the column headings on that output; the "M1" and "M2" headers seem to both be over a single column.

Comment: So, pos and f1_index are converted to index. Rest of the values for each column then converted to list. So, the final code is reading two cell values (list) at a time from the same column, and then creating product or zip based upon the def (mapfun). Clear?

Comment: No, sorry, it's not clear at all.  For instance, in the original data the first row is `["G/G", "G/G", "G"]`.  Why is the output for that row `["CgG,CgG,CgG,CgG", "CgG,CgG,CgG,CgG", "CgG"]`?

Comment: You see the return part of the mapfun: **return ','.join('g'.join(t) for t in...** So the function is multiplying the list values from adjacent lines in the same column. These product or zip is joined by 'g'.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Would you be able to help me out regarding this problem. I think chat would be more appropriate. Thanks